# What nameservers should I use for GitHub Pages when using a custom domain?

Tags: domains, nameserver, github

I am using a custom domain for a GitHub Pages site. They said to set `CNAME` or `A` record. But what nameservers should I use? What is the default, or should I leave it blank?

Comment: You can't set both the NAMESERVERS _and_ the CNAME/A records at your domain registrar - the two are mutually exclusive. If you set the NAMESERVERS then you are instructing another server to handle your DNS, in which case any locally defined DNS records will be ignored.

Answer (score 10):

You answered your own question.

> They said to set CNAME or A record.

As for the Name servers, unless GitHub says otherwise, you are going to ask what the A record or CNAME should be set on your domain name. Then, if you don't know how, ask your Domain Name Registrar about setting the CNAME or A record to what it needs to be for your domain name.

Answer (score 5):

AFAIK unless somethings changed you arent able to use Namesevers as they are used for the main domain, you will have to use a A domain or a CNAME to cover the domain. Sorry to break the news to you.

Answer (score 2):

The "default" nameservers are typically the nameservers owned by your domain registrar, and your registrar should have a button to fill them in automatically. If edits to your `A` and `CNAME` records are working, that means your nameservers are right already and you don't need to make any modifications to them.